# How to find the rest of list after combinations

Tags: python

Could you please help me with this situation?
I have 3 lists.

```
list1 = [ "a", "b", "c", "d"]
list2 = ["x", "y", "z"]
list3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

First, I need to take 3 element of list1, 2 elements of list2, and 4 elements from list3 then combine them like:

```
[a, b, c, x, y, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[a, b, c, x, z, 1, 2, 3, 5]
[a, b, c, x, z, 1, 2, 3, 6]
[a, b, c, x, z, 1, 2, 3, 7]
....
```

Then I need to print out 3 elements of the rest of list3 at the end:

```
[a, b, c, x, y, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
[a, b, c, x, z, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7]
[a, b, c, x, z, 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7]
[a, b, c, x, z, 1, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5, 6]
....
```

I used subtraction of 2 lists, but it showed error

```
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'itertools.combinations'
```

...

```
combi1 = combinations(list1, 3)
combi2 = combinations(list2, 2)
combi3 = combinations(list3, 4)
rest3 = list3 -  combi3
com = product(combi1, combi2, combi3)
```

Please help me with this problem!
Many thank!

python

Comment: welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. ... [Why “Can someone help me?” is not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Could you please edit your question and make it clearer? This really helps everyone out.

Comment: [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Adding expected results here would also be very helpful.

Comment: Here are what I expect: ```[a, b, c, x, y, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
[a, b, c, x, z, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7]
[a, b, c, x, z, 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7]
[a, b, c, x, z, 1, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5, 6]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check with `chain` flatten the list of tuple after `product`, for getting the rest of list , you can using `set`-`set`(notice this will need you do not have overlap in your list1 to list3)

```
from itertools import combinations, product, chain
combi1 = list(combinations(list1, 3))
combi2 = list(combinations(list2, 2))
combi3 = list(combinations(list3, 4))

l=list(product(list(combi1), list(combi2), list(combi3)))

l=[list(chain(*x))for x in l]

rest=[set(list1+list2+list3) - set(x)for x in l ]
```

Comment: thank you. May I ask how can I print out the rest of list3 at the end of each combinations like this: ```[a, b, c, x, y, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
[a, b, c, x, z, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7]
[a, b, c, x, z, 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7]
[a, b, c, x, z, 1, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5, 6]```